# Can you alloc an object whose parent class uses the autorelease pool?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a subclass that i use alloc and init to instantiate.  In the init method I go

```
self = [self initWithRect:spriteManager.imageRect spriteManager:spriteManager.manager];
```

So the parent constructor is using the autorelease pool.  So what happens here?  If I try to release the object I get an error.  Should I change my init method to be a convience constructor as well to conform to the alloc, copy, new ownership policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The superclass's initializer -initWithRect:spriteManager: does *not* put the object into the autorelease pool. The naming convention is that any -init… method sets up an object which you are responsible for releasing.

Xcode provides helpful code completion templates for init and dealloc methods. Just press **control-comma** and start typing "init" or "dealloc". (You can also type init and press control-comma.) The init template is

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Your initializations
    }
    return self;
}
```

You'd replace `self = [super init]` with the line you wrote above.

The dealloc template is

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    // Your deallocations
    [super dealloc];
}
```

`[super dealloc]` invokes the superclass's -dealloc, which would take care of releasing whatever it set up in your -initWithRect:spriteManager: call (as well as anything it inherits from its superclass).